# How to remove pipe separator of the first list item on the line?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a pipe list that stretches out to multiple lines. Using jquery how can I remove the list separator for the first element on each line.

**Like this:**

Red | Green | Blue

Purple | Black | White

Violet | Yellow | Magenta

So far, I have this (from an answer on stackoverflow):

**jQuery**:

```
  var maxWidth = 350, // Your div max-width
    totalWidth = 0;
  $('#footer .right .links ul li').each(function(){
      var currentWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
          nextWidth = $(this).next().outerWidth();
      totalWidth += currentWidth;
      if ( (totalWidth + nextWidth) > maxWidth ) {
          $(this).css('border-left', 'none');
          totalWidth = 0;
      }
  });
```

**CSS**:

```
#footer .right .links {
  float:left;
  width: 350px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
#footer .right .links ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:right;
}
#footer .right .links ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:0 5px 0 7px;
    border-left:1px solid #7d7d7d;
}
#footer .right .links ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
    border-left:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="">Green</a></li>
<li><a href="">Yellow</a></li>
....
</ul>
```

---

**EDIT (the solution based on Faust's answer):**
The user Faust had the correct answer but it had to be tweaked a bit. The left offsets for all the elements are:

```
720 763 830 900 703 776 854 944
```

As you can see, the left offset for the first element on each line isn't 0. I noticed that the left offset of the first element of each line is smaller than the previous one.

Here's the tweaked jquery:

```
  $('#footer .right .links > ul li').each(function(){
      var $thisLi = $(this);
      var offset_left = $thisLi.position().left;
      if ($thisLi.prev().position()) {
        var offest_prev_left = $thisLi.prev().position().left;
      } else {
        var offest_prev_left = 0;
      }
      $('#test').append(offset_left + ' ');
      if(offset_left < offest_prev_left){
        $thisLi.css('border-left', 'none')
      }
  });
```

Comment: You want to build an array of entries from the string? Like the PHP `explode()` or `split()` command?

Comment: Can you add your HTML too?

Comment: This seems overkill for what you are trying to do

Comment: How are your pipes currently generated? Are they characters in HTML, or are they left- or right-borders in CSS?

Comment: @Cris: Just revised my answer based on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get the offsets from the parent container's grid, then if the left-offset is 0, you know it's wrapped down to a next line:

```
$('#footer .right .links ul li').each(function(){
    var $thisLi = $(this);
    var offset = $thisLi.position();
    if(offset.left == 0){
        $thisLi.css('border-left', 'none')
    }
});
```

**UPDATE** Now I can see from your fiddle that you are aligning the items to the right (sorry, didn't catch that from your CSS). You should use border-right on the list-items rather than border-left. I've also taken note which item should be acting as the offset container (the div with the `links` class), and applied position: relative, so that `position()` will the coordinates relative to that div.

Here is my revised code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var $container = $('#footer .right .links');

    $('#footer .right .links ul li').each(function(){
    var $thisLi = $(this);
    var offset = $thisLi.position();

    if(offset.left >= $container.width() - $thisLi.outerWidth()){
        $thisLi.css('border-right', 'none')
    }
    });
});
```

And here is a revised fiddle, showing it working. :

http://jsfiddle.net/j7LKW/2/

Note that I've changed a few lines in your CSS:

- I added `position:relative` to `#footer .right .links`
- and
  changed the border declaration from `border-left` to `border-right`
  in `#footer .right .links ul li`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j7LKW/ and it doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The left offset for my elements are 720 763 830 900 703 776 854 944 so this must be the problem. The item with the offset 703 is the first item on the 2nd line.

Comment: A much more elegant solution! Works great, thanks! How did you get so good with jQuery? Books?

Answer (score 0):

```
var entries = "Red | Green | Blue | Purple | Orange ....";
var colors = entries.split(" | ");
var firstL = colors.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

What don't you just use

```
#footer .right .links ul li:first-child
{ 
    border-left: none;
}

#footer .right .links ul li:last-child
{ 
    border-right: none;
}
```